# How to use factory pattern in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not much understand about this pattern yet so I try to check some Jquery plugin and follow their structure However I want to reuse this plugin.

Here is Code

```
(function (factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {

    // AMD. Register as anonymous module.

    define(['jquery'], factory);
  } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    // Node / CommonJS
    factory(require('jquery'));
  } else {
    // Browser globals.
    factory(jQuery);
  }
}) (function ($) {
  'use strict';

  var console = window.console || { log: function () {} };

  function Testing($element, $els) {

    this.$Form = $($elementss);
    this.$Input = this.$Form.find($els);
    this.init();
  }

    Testing.prototype = {
    constructor: Testing,

    init: function () {
      this.addListener();
    },

    addListener : function () {
      this.$Input.on('change', $.proxy(this.changeIt, this));
    },

    changeIt: function (e) {

        console.log(e)

    }    
  };

  $(function (e) {

    return new Testing($('#form'), '.inputClass');

  });

});
```

As the above I can call it on **return new Testing($('#form'), '.inputClass');** But how can I do if i want to use it with another selectors.

Comment: This is called the *universal module definition*, in short UMD, pattern. A transpiler can automatically generate it for you.

Comment: How and why close?

Comment: Because I have no idea what your problem with "*i want to use it with another selectors*" is. Just change the selector to something else? Or create multiple `new Testing(…)` instances with different parameters?

Comment: How can we use new Testing(…) outside or anywhere??

Comment: You'd export it and import your module elsewhere. As I said, use a module system and let your bundler or transpiler generate this thing for you.

Comment: Should you give me a small simple

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130058/discussion-between-heng-sopheak-and-bergi).